# Jwplayer 7 lightsout and iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, jwplayer

I just included lightsout olugin in jwplayer, so its work fine when I add jwplayer code in my page but when I call jwplayer with an iframe lightsout plugin works inside the iframe and does no effect to the page any more.

Below I have the javascript

```
(function(e) {
    function t(t, n, i) {
        function a() {
            for (var e in g) n[e] === void 0 && (n[e] = g[e]);
            if (y = document.createElement("div"), y.className += " BSlightsout_shade", y.style.display = "none", y.style.backgroundColor = "#" + n.backgroundcolor, y.style.zIndex = 0, y.style.opacity = 0, y.style.filter = "alpha(opacity=0)", y.style.top = 0, y.style.left = 0, y.style.bottom = 0, y.style.right = 0, n.parentid ? (y.style.position = "absolute", document.getElementById(n.parentid).style.position = "relative", document.getElementById(n.parentid).appendChild(y)) : (y.style.position = "fixed", document.body.appendChild(y)), y.onclick = r, p = new o(y, n.time, n.opacity, s), u.on = p.on, u.off = p.off, u.toggle = p.toggle, n.dockicon === !0 && typeof t.addButton == "function") {
                var i = l + "BSlightsout.png";
                t.addButton(i, "Cinema Mode", p.toggle, "BSlightsout")
            }
            t.onIdle(d), t.onPlay(d), t.onPause(d), t.onComplete(f)
        }

        function s() {
            var o, n = 0;
            while ((o = e(n++)) && o.hasOwnProperty("id") && 100 > n) c(o, "auto");
            c(t, 301)
        }

        function c(e, t) {
            e.getRenderingMode() === "html5" ? e.getContainer().style.zIndex = t : e.getContainer().parentNode.style.zIndex = t
        }

        function r() {
            t.pause(!0), p.on()
        }

        function f() {
            n.oncomplete == "off" ? p.off() : p.on()
        }

        function d() {
            switch (t.getState()) {
                case "IDLE":
                    n.onidle == "off" ? p.off() : p.on();
                    break;
                case "PLAYING":
                    n.onplay == "off" ? p.off() : p.on();
                    break;
                case "PAUSED":
                    n.onpause == "off" ? p.off() : p.on()
            }
        }
        var y, p, u = this,
            g = {
                backgroundcolor: "000000",
                dockicon: !0,
                opacity: 1,
                time: 800,
                onidle: "on",
                onplay: "off",
                onpause: "on",
                oncomplete: "on",
                parentid: null
            };
        t.onReady(a), this.getDisplayElement = function() {
            return i
        }, this.resize = function() {}
    }

    function o(e, t, o, n) {
        function i(e) {
            l.element.style.opacity = "" + e, l.element.style.filter = "alpha(opacity=" + Math.round(e * 100) + ")", l.opacity = e
        }
        this.element = e, this.time = t || 1e3, this.dark = o || .8, this.opacity = 0;
        var a, l = this,
            s = "opacity" in this.element.style;
        s || (this.element.style.zoom = 1), this.off = function() {
            typeof n == "function" && n(), l.element.style.display = "block", clearInterval(a);
            var e = (new Date).getTime(),
                t = l.opacity;
            a = setInterval(function() {
                var o = ((new Date).getTime() - e) / l.time;
                1 > o || (o = 1, clearInterval(a)), i(l.dark * o + t * (1 - o))
            }, 1e3 / 60)
        }, this.on = function() {
            clearInterval(a);
            var e = (new Date).getTime(),
                t = l.opacity;
            a = setInterval(function() {
                var o = ((new Date).getTime() - e) / l.time;
                1 > o || (o = 1, clearInterval(a), l.element.style.display = "none"), i(0 * o + t * (1 - o))
            }, 1e3 / 60)
        }, this.toggle = function() {
            .5 > l.opacity ? l.off() : l.on()
        }
    }
    for (var n = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].getElementsByTagName("script"), i = 0; n.length > i; i++) {
        var a = n[i].src.match(/(.*?)BSlightsout-?\d?\.js/);
        if (a) {
            var l = a[1];
            break
        }
    }
    e().registerPlugin("BSlightsout", "6.0", t)
})(jwplayer)
```

as I told you before when I load jwplayer code in page its working and turning lights off but when in the same page I call jwplayer with an iframe code its turning lights off inside the iframe and does no any effect in my page.

Is there anyway to turn off lights using external jwplayer via iframe code?

```
plugins: { 'jwplayer/plugins/BSlightsout.js': {}, },
```

Comment: do you see any error in console ? can you provide URL for this ?

Comment: Hi, I dont see any error in console as I told you its working but when I call the page as iframe its working inside the embedded page and does not effect to in site.Im working localy

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use that bloated plugin. This pen has all the code you need to achieve the desired effect.

```
function turnOutLights() {
    $('.lights-overlay').css('background', 'rgba(1, 1, 1, 1)');
    $('.lights-overlay').css({ opacity: 0.9 });
    $('.lights-overlay').css('visibility', 'visible');
    $('#previewPlayer').addClass('zout');
}

function hideOverlay() {
    $('.lights-overlay').css({ opacity: 0.6 });
    $('.lights-overlay').css('visibility', 'hidden');
    $('#previewPlayer').removeClass('zout');
}

jwplayer("previewPlayer").setup({
  playlist: [{
    file: "http://distribution.bbb3d.renderfarming.net/video/mp4/bbb_sunflower_1080p_60fps_normal.mp4"
    }],
        width: 720,
        aspectratio: '16:9',
        autostart: true
      });
```

http://codepen.io/simsketch/pen/eBwqmV

Comment: Yes Elon thanks, but that one which I have posted is just a plugin of jwplayer and is adding the button directly in player I know also other jquery plugins for this you are right and your code is fine thankyou but my question is different

Comment: oh ok i didn't realize it's a jwplayer plugin...very cool. I don't think you will be able to make this plugin work inside of an iframe in the way that you want it to.

Comment: You are right I think so too, couldnt find the any way yet and I dont think that its possible. :(

Comment: Yeah, you're forced to implement the overlay plugin on the parent page.